# Java Storing data as sublevels

Tags: java, mysql

I’m in front of project where i should think of kinda accounting system development. And there is very big amount of data. But with data all is clear it could be stored in MySql.
The thing is, there will be stored spare parts for vehicles. And in first level there is for example part as engine, but then the engine consist of smaller parts, and these smaller parts also consist of smaller parts. And I just don’t know the best thing to make this system.
I need to store them so i can click on first item as for example engine and it shows me all parts it consist of, and then i can click of any of these parts and it shows again all parts it consist of.

What should i use to make it happen? Or maybe anyone can say other method to make this system? Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The most suitable data structure to hold the informations is a tree:

- each node is a Part
- children of a Part are Part and conceptually they are subparts
- if you need to navigate back from a subpart to his parent part you goes to the parent Part

Here is the code:

```
public class Part {
    private String name;
    private Part parent;
    private List<Part> children;

    public Part(String name, Part parent) {
       this.name = name;
       this.children = new ArrayList();
       this.parent = parent;
       if (parent != null) {
          parent.getChildren().add(this);
       }
    }

    ...
}

...
Part car = new Part("car", null);
Part engine = new Part("engine", car);
Part piston = new Part("piston", engine);
Part cilinder = new Part("cilinder", engine);
```

and you can see that from car you can see details of car, and access his children (engine in this case). From engine you can go back to car, or you can see the subparts (piston and cilinder). Graphically this is the situation:

```
                          car
                           |
                           |
                        engine
                           |
                    ---------------
                    |             |
                cilinder        piston
```

This java structure can be reproduced in a single table with self references in a relational database as follow

```
 PARTS
 -------------------------------
 ID         NAME         PARENT_ID
 1          car          <null>
 2          engine       1
 3          cilinder     2
 4          piston       2
```

You can use it with any level of deep

In the case you need to reuse parts in different areas you can save them in the db as follow (note that bolts are reused):

```
PARTS
ID     NAME
-------------------
1      car
2      engine
3      piston
4      cilinder
5      bolt
```

and relate them with a NODES tables

```
PART_NODES
ID   ID_PART   ID_PARENT
----------------------------------------------
1    1         <null>
2    2         1
3    3         2
4    4         2
5    5         1    <---- bolt are used as part of car
6    5         2    <---- and as part of engine
```

where the graphical presentation is the following

```
                   1 -> car
                   |
           -----------------
           |               |
           2 -> engine     5 -> bolt
           |
 ---------------------------
|            |              |
3 -> piston  4 -> cilinder  5 -> bolt
```

In java this is reflected as a class `Part` referenced by a class `PartNode` using code similar to the previous for linking nodes together.

Comment: The single-table method is assuming that a part entry is not going to be re-used and may not be part of other components too. If you were to store some additional information for a part (such as price?), ideally you would have a one-to-many relationship (you would not want to repeat a part for every other part using a part of this type). This may work if you are referencing EXACT entities, which doesn't seem to be the case in this context

Comment: If you need to reuse parts between different areas You can eventually use a PART_NODE table and replace NAME column with PART_ID reference. I update the answer